# Killing a process from a new command prompt in a batch file

Tags: windows, process, batch-file, cmd, taskkill

I have this sitting in a batch file, and I'm wondering why it's throwing

> "The system cannot find the file TASKLIST"

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 skip=2" %%i IN (TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe") DO taskkill /F /PID %%i
```

More importantly, the problem is that that command - killing explorer.exe - has to run in the cmd spawned by the command

```
at xx:xx /interactive "cmd.exe"
```

How would I pipe that taskkill command into the new command prompt that would be spawned by the at command?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to process a exit of a command use single qutoes or back quotes with "backq" parameter:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 skip=2" %%i IN ('TASKLIST /FI ^"IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe^"') DO taskkill /F /PID %%i
```

(im not sure if your backquotes are displayed because they meta-symbol for code block in stackoverflow)

Taskkill also can kill a process by image name

```
taskkill /im explorer* /f
```

Comment: Oh that makes the process so much easier XD Thank you very much. Do you know to send this to the "at" command?

Comment: what did you tried?Beter use SCHTASKS - you'll have more control over the scheduling.